# SQLite. "UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table2);" is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why this construction is not working in SQLite:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table2);
```

where column1 and column2 has the same number of rows and the same type.

Comment: this will not work is there any common column between two table ?

Comment: yes, this is column Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the common column to look up the matching record:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT column2
               FROM table2
               WHERE table2.Name = table1.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to work because the table1.column1 only wants one value. What you are actually doing is setting table1.column1 = all the results from table2.column2.

You will probably have to join the two tables together on a common column or key

Answer (score 0):

Because nested select returns more than one row probably. You try to put all the data from table2 into 1 element in table1

Answer (score 0):

Is Column1 just getting the same value all the way down the column?  Otherwise, you need to do a JOIN in the update here and Set Column1 = Column2 based on the join.

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking the two tables
so it is trying to put all column2 values into each table1 row.

Link the two together with a field such as
    Update table1 set column1 = column2
    from table2 where table1.ColumnA = tables2.ColumnA

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your statement isn't working is because you're telling it to put all of the values for `column2` into every `column1` cell in table1.  You want something more like:

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    table1.column1 = table2.column2
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2
ON
    table1.id = table2.table1_id
```